# Why am I getting 404 error page on subpages on my test site sitting in subfolder of my live site?

Tags: ee1, config, 404

I have created a test version of my site in a subfolder of my live site.

The root of my live site is in /public_html and my test site is in 
/public_html/test.mydomain.com.

I have set up a dns record for the subdomain to point to the subfolder.

I have copied the database and linked the test site to the test database.

I have edited the entries in the config file as follows. If the main site entry is:

```
$conf['tmpl_file_basepath'] = "/usr/www/users/capeto/system/template_files";
```

... the test site entry is:

```
$conf['tmpl_file_basepath'] = "/usr/www/users/capeto/test.mysite.com/system/template_files";
```

The homepage of my test site displays fine,but none of the subpages. I am getting a 404 on all of them. For example the page http://test.mysite.com/about/ returns a 404 page.

In the template debugging code it says:

```
(0.001131) Template group and template not found, showing 404 page
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an .htaccess file in the test.mysite.com/ directory too? You will need one if you are removing index.php. You can try going to http://test.mysite.com/index.php/about to see if this may be your issue.

Comment: If possible you should not use `.htaccess` files, but modify (or add an Apache file to) your site's configuration that does the redirect. `.htaccess` files are a security risk, and by Apache's own admission slow your responses down because Apache has to read all the `.htaccess` files on a per-directory basis rather than all at once when the web server starts up. [Reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when)